# The margin of a div respect its parent

Tags: html, css

I am confused about the margins. I have a logo inside a div content. If I give a margin-top to the div logo this margin appears between the content and the page. Why?

Here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/bCkpb/

CSS:

```
#content {
    position:relative;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:300px; height:250px;
    background-color:blue;
}

#logo {
    margin:20px auto; /* Why this 20px appear between the page and the content? */
    width:120px; height:120px;
    background:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="logo"> </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the top-margin of a block-level element and the top-margin of its first block-level child will always [collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins) (unless any border, padding, line boxes or clearance separate them). One way to prevent this behaviour is to add an `overflow` value other than visible to the `#content` div. You can also change the display value of `#content` to inline-block.

http://jsfiddle.net/bCkpb/3/